# How to get index of an item in java.util.Set

Tags: java, set

I know the differences between Set and List(unique vs. duplications allowed, not ordered/ordered, etc). What I'm looking for is a set that keeps the elements ordered(that's easy), but I also need to be able to recover the index in which an element was inserted. So if I insert four elements, then I want to be able to know the order in which one of them was inserted.

```
MySet<String> set = MySet<String>();
set.add("one");
set.add("two");
set.add("three");
set.add("four");

int index = set.getIndex("two");
```

So at any given moment I can check if a String was already added, and get the index of the string in the set. Is there anything like this, or I need to implement it myself?

Comment: What would you expect getIndex to return if you'd removed "one" in the meantime?

Comment: if it's not in commons-collections http://commons.apache.org/collections/ then I think you'll have to implement it yourself

Comment: Well, since the set should be ordered, if an element is removed all the elements inserted after that would be reallocated one position. I suppose that if I do a getIndex of an element that does not exist, or has been removed, I would get a -1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A small static custom method in a `Util` class would help:

```
 public static <T> int getIndex(Set<T> set, T value) {
   int result = 0;
   for (T entry:set) {
     if (entry.equals(value)) return result;
     result++;
   }
   return -1;
 }
```

If you need/want one class that *is a* `Set` and offers a `getIndex()` method, I strongly suggest to implement a new `Set` and use the decorator pattern:

```
 public class IndexAwareSet<T> implements Set {
   private Set<T> set;
   public IndexAwareSet(Set<T> set) {
     this.set = set;
   }

   // ... implement all methods from Set and delegate to the internal Set

   public int getIndex(T entry) {
     int result = 0;
     for (T entry:set) {
       if (entry.equals(value)) return result;
       result++;
     }
     return -1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. One question, is it worth to call contains(T entry) before iterating through the Set?

Comment: @Jose - depends on the Set. HashSet: yes, contains runs in O(1). TreeSet - no, as contains need O(n) exactly like the `getIndex` algorithm. So it would take twice as long.

Comment: Note that if you decorate a HashSet, you won't get the desired behavior (i.e. index according to insertion order). You must provide a Set whose iteration order matched the insertion order. LinkedHashSet is capable of it.

Comment: -1: I still don't see how this response answers the original problem. There is no guarantee that the indices will reflect the insertion order. Iteration over TreeSet or HashSet will not necessarily follow the insertion order.

Comment: @Eyal - (1) TreeSet does not preserve insertion order others mentioned, OP should use `LinkedHashSet`. (2) both snippets/examples can be used with *any* `Set` implementation. You just need to say `new IndexAwareSet(new LinkedHashSet())` and it should work as expected. BTW - I mentioned HashSet and TreeSet only to answer Jose's question in his comment, not in the answer.

Comment: @Andreas_D sorry for the bump, but `TreeSet.contains` is actually O(log n) :p This algorithm is a linear search, while `TreeSet` uses a binary search.

Answer (score 41):

After creating Set just convert it to List and get by index from List:

```
Set<String> stringsSet = new HashSet<>();
stringsSet.add("string1");
stringsSet.add("string2");

List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<>(stringsSet);
stringsList.get(0); // "string1";
stringsList.get(1); // "string2";
```

Comment: I believe the question was how to get the index of an item in a set and not how to get an item by an index.

Comment: stringsList.indexOf("string1");

Answer (score 3):

you can extend [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) adding your desired `getIndex()` method. It's 15 minutes to implement and test it. Just go through the set using iterator and counter, check the object for equality. If found, return the counter.

Comment: TreeSet will not keep the order in which the elements were added, they will be ordered in their natural order.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (though not very pretty) is to use Apache common List/Set mutation

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.SetUniqueList;

final List<Long> vertexes=SetUniqueList.setUniqueList(new LinkedList<>());
```

it is a list without duplicates

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html

Answer (score 0):

How about add the strings to a hashtable where the value is an index:

```
  Hashtable<String, Integer> itemIndex = new Hashtable<>();
  itemIndex.put("First String",1);
  itemIndex.put("Second String",2);
  itemIndex.put("Third String",3);

  int indexOfThirdString = itemIndex.get("Third String");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send your set data to a new list

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.addAll(uniqueNameSet);
myList.indexOf("xxx");
```