# Assign an element that is removed from HashSet to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, hashset

I want to remove first element of a HashSet and assign this removed element to another variable. Since its remove function returns boolean I can't do this. How can I obtain its removed value ? Thanks.
My code is

```
  HashSet<Node> List = new HashSet<Node>();
  expandList.add(s);
  while(expandList.size() > 0)
   {
     Node toAssigned = List.remove(s);
   // other works related with toAssigned are here

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4395920) of [Vladimir Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473070/vladimir-ivanov):

> you can extend `LinkedHash` adding your desired `getIndex()` method.
>
> Just go through the set using iterator and counter, check the object for equality. If found, return the counter.

or you can try [Kiryl Ivanou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931613/kiryl-ivanou)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199097):

> After creating Set just convert it to List and get by index from List:
>
> ```
> Set<String> stringsSet = new HashSet<>();
> stringsSet.add("string1");
> stringsSet.add("string2");
>
> List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<>(stringsSet);
> stringsList.get(0); // "string1";
> stringsList.get(1); // "string2";
> ```

Comment: But isn't it efcect the performance? This code is a part of BFS algorithm for 8 puzzle game. I have to use HashSet because of my advisor since he says arrayList is too slow     @mahdad

Comment: @user3864949 : 
HashSet ensures there are no duplicates, gives you an O(1) contains() method but doesn't preserve order.

ArrayList doesn't ensure there are no duplicates, contains() is O(n) but you can control the order of the entries.

Comment: @user3864949 I believe using the hash set has a better performance than an array list. but you need do it for your question

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a first element in a HashSet as the sequence order is unspecified. Perhaps, the Queue data structure would be a better fit for you needs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

If you need to remove an element from the set without being concerned as to which element you remove, you can use the following:

```
set.iterator().next()
```